# Stuck on "Tap Portal to Interact"

Tags: ingress

I recently claimed my first portal - yay me! - but since doing so, that portal is highlighted (regardless of my distance to it) by a marker that says "Tap Portal to Interact".  It no longer shows me nearby portals because it seems to think I'm still in the tutorial, even though I followed the steps like it showed me (and then repeated them several times, I did the apparently-standard route of deploying all eight resonators roughly equidistant from one another at the outer edge of the portal's action radius).  Here's what all I've tried to clear it:

- I "visited" that portal from my Portal Key and tapped the portal like it wanted.  It brought up the portal menu with nothing highlighted by a marker, but in the background I could still see the marker on the portal telling me to tap it.  Sure enough, when I left that menu, the marker was still there.
- Force Sync
- Started and Aborted the Training missions having do with Resonators.  The other marker put itself over the Training markers, making it where I couldn't read the instructions to complete the Training missions even if I wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to clear (without resetting the tutorials, which I was afraid would cause me to have to do every tutorial over again).  I toggled "Quick Wakeup" in the Ops -> Device menu, which notified me that I needed to restart Ingress to finish changing the setting.  I allowed Ingress to restart and the tutorial was gone, and several unclaimed portals near me appeared!